# Macro to repeat the same process from row no .2 till last row where data is found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Macro code as below. This Macro basically copies a string from 1st cell in column A of sheet 2 and finds it in column A of sheet 1 of the same workbook. After searching, it copies and pastes the entire row into the sheet 1. I have written a code as below. I need the same process to happen from row 2 till last row and populate the row data in column A of sheet 1.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D9").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="F7P51PA#UUF", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B121").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("C118").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="F7P99PA#UUF", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B3:E3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B174").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D167").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="F7Q00PA#UUF", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B4:E4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B175").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D162").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="F7Q07PA#UUF", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B5:E5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B182").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E176").Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with this code changing the range in for loop...

```
Public Sub macro5()

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("A2").Activate
    For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A100")
        If cel <> Empty Then
            With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
                x = cel.Value
               Set c = .Find(What:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
               y = c.Address
               If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Range(y).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 5).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(y).Offset(0, 1)
               End If
            End With
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```